# Python IDLE 3.5 invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, traceback

I'm new to python, and I can't figure out how to make this work, it just wont work. (other answers won't help me)

Here's my code:

```
# My First Python Game Thing
# Aka Endless Walking Simulator
game_temp1 = True
def choiceroom_thing1():
    while game_temp1:
        directionchoice = input('L(left)R(Right)B(Backwards)F(Forwards)')
        direction = int(directionchoice)
        if direction in ['L', 'R','B', 'F']:
          game_temp1 = False
        if direction == "L":
              print ('You went Left!')
        if direction == "R":
              print ('You went Right!')
        if direction == "B":
              print ('You went Backwards!')
        if direction == "F":
              print ('You went Forwards!')
        game_temp1 = True
        room_count = room_count + 1
        choiceroom_thing1()
print ('Hello Jeff...')
print ('Heres my first game')
print ("Adventure Game")
input("Press Any Key To Continue...")
room_count = 1
while game_temp1:
    directionchoice = input('L(left)R(Right)B(Backwards)F(Forwards)')
    direction = int(directionchoice)
    if direction in ['L', 'R','B', 'F']:
      game_temp1 = False
    if direction == "L":
          print ('You went Left!')
    if direction == "R":
          print ('You went Right!')
    if direction == "B":
          print ('You went Backwards!')
    if direction == "F":
          print ('You went Forwards!')
    game_temp1 = True
    room_count = room_count + 1
    choiceroom_thing1()
```

And then I get this error when I run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/PythonProjects/Blah From Book.py", line 27,
line 27, in <module>
    direction = int(directionchoice)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ':'
```

Can someone please fix my code?

Comment: You are asking for a letter as input, it can't be converted to an `int`

Comment: Why the heck are you calling `int` when you asked the user to type `L`, `R`, `B`, or `F`?

Comment: What do i replace int with then?

Comment: This is legit my first day learning python.

Comment: Nothing, input is a string, which is what you want

Comment: You don't convert the letter to an integer.  Let it remain a string.  Delete that statement.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to convert `directionchoice` to an `int`.
`direction`  should be equal to `directionchoice`.
Then test if `direction` is not in the wanted choices:

```
if direction not in ['L', 'R','B', 'F']:
```